# Sharepoint Calculated Column Substring

Tags: sharepoint, excel, excel-formula, calculated-columns

Need help with a Calculated column issue in SharePoint 2007

Basically, I'm trying to take the value from the [Contact E-Mail Address] column and remove the mailto: part infront which Sharepoint automatically created.

Original Column Value : mailto:foo@fooo.com
Calculated column required value: foo@fooo.com

This is what i've got so far :
=RIGHT([Contact E-Mail Address],11)

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: This is great but how did you get [Contact email address] out of SharePoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

=RIGHT([Contact E-Mail Address],LEN([Contact E-Mail Address])-7)

or

=SUBSTITUTE([Contact E-Mail Address],"mailto:","")

Adapted from [Excel Tips](http://excel.tips.net/Pages/T002897_Extracting_Email_Addresses_from_Hyperlinks.html) (calculated columns use Excel functions)

Comment: SUBSTITUTE() throws an error for me, but RIGHT() and LEN() both seem to work